# quiz next button not working when a json row is delete using php and jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i used the code below to create a quiz and it works well and **nextbutton** works perfect if the `Que_id` is for instance **(1,2,3,4)** but this will not work properlly **(1,3,4)** . as you can see, **question id 2** has been deleted and this will result in many **nextbutton** instead of just normal One **nextbutton**.

But my problem is this, if i delete a row from the json file for example

```
"que_id":"1","que_desc":"The Best Coders Network","ans1":"Stackoverflow","ans2":"none","ans3":"none"}
```

or

```
{"que_id":"3","que_desc":"Stackoverflow was founded in what year","ans1":"2008","ans2":"none","ans3":"none"}
```

, the quiz will no longer be showing the quiz questions one by one via **next button** rather it will display all the nextbutton at once. If i then try to click any of the scattered next button, it will post the result.

on php end, It seems the quiz is submitted based on the **que_id** which is then passed to javascript incremented functions.

Can someone help me with this. I want the nextbutton to works perfect and display the quiz question one by one no matter which rows was deleted in json file.

below is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <?php    
    $data = '[{"que_id":"1","que_desc":"The Best Coders Network","ans1":"Stackoverflow","ans2":"none","ans3":"none"},
    {"que_id":"2","que_desc":"Who Founded Stackoverflow","ans1":"Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky.","ans2":"none","ans3":"none"},
    {"que_id":"3","que_desc":"Stackoverflow was founded in what year","ans1":"2008","ans2":"none","ans3":"none"},
    {"que_id":"4","que_desc":"Stack Overflow is a privately held by a website","ans1":"Stack Exchange Network","ans2":"none","ans3":"none"}]';    
    $characters = json_decode($data);
    //echo $characters->que_desc;    
    //echo print_r($characters);
    //var_dump($characters);    
    ?>

    <form method='post' id='quiz_form'>
      <?php
      foreach ($characters as $value) {
          $result['que_id']=  $value->que_id ;
          $result['que_desc']= $value->que_desc ;
          $result['ans1']= $value->ans1 ;
          $result['ans2']= $value->ans2 ;
          $result['ans3']= $value->ans3 ;    
    ?>
        <div id="question_<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>" class='questions'>
          <h2 id="question_<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>">
            <?php echo $result['que_id'].".".$result['que_desc'];?>
          </h2>
          <div class='align'>
            <label class="containerg">
    <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>'>
    <label id='ans1_<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>' for='1'><?php echo $result['ans1'];?></label>
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="containerg">
    <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio2_<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>'>
    <label id='ans2_<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>' for='1'><?php echo $result['ans2'];?></label>
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="containerg">
    <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio3_<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>'>
    <label id='ans3_<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>' for='1'><?php echo $result['ans3'];?></label>
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>

            <input type="radio" checked='checked' value="5" style='display:none' id='radio4_<?php echo $result[' que_id '];?>' name='<?php echo $result[' que_id '];?>'>
          </div>
          <br/>
          <input type="button" id='next<?php echo $result[' que_id '];?>' value='Next!' name='question' />
        </div>
        <?php }?>
    </form>
    <div id='result'>
      Result will Appear Here test
      <br/>
    </div>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var steps = $('form').find(".questions");
        var count = steps.size();
        steps.each(function(i) {
          hider = i + 2;
          if (i == 0) {
            $("#question_" + hider).hide();
            createNextButton(i);
          } else if (count == i + 1) {
            var step = i + 1;

            $("#next" + step).on('click', function() {
              submit();
            });
          } else {
            $("#question_" + hider).hide();
            createNextButton(i);
          }
        });

        function submit() {
          // post to ajax
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(msg) {
              $("#quiz_form,#demo1").addClass("hide");
              $('#result').show();
              $('#result').append(msg);
            }
          });
        }

        function createNextButton(i) {
          var step = i + 1;
          var step1 = i + 2;
          $('#next' + step).on('click', function() {
            $("#question_" + step).hide();
            $("#question_" + step1).show();
          });
        }
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code the that you are creating element using the data with given id values and in your jQuery event bind logic you assume that these values are always in continuation. 
If you remove any row from the data the continuation and the logc both will be broken.

You need to update your logic based on the class selector.

You can update your code logic like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

<?php


$data = '[{"que_id":"1","que_desc":"The Best Coders Network","ans1":"Stackoverflow","ans2":"none","ans3":"none"},
{"que_id":"2","que_desc":"Who Founded Stackoverflow","ans1":"Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky.","ans2":"none","ans3":"none"},
{"que_id":"3","que_desc":"Stackoverflow was founded in what year","ans1":"2008","ans2":"none","ans3":"none"},
{"que_id":"4","que_desc":"Stack Overflow is a privately held by a website","ans1":"Stack Exchange Network","ans2":"none","ans3":"none"}]';



$characters = json_decode($data);
//echo $characters->que_desc;

//echo print_r($characters);
//var_dump($characters);


?>

<form method='post' id='quiz_form'>

<?php
foreach ($characters as $value) {
      $result['que_id']=  $value->que_id ;
    $result['que_desc']= $value->que_desc ;
        $result['ans1']= $value->ans1 ;
        $result['ans2']= $value->ans2 ;
        $result['ans3']= $value->ans3 ;



?>
<div id="question_<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>" class='questions'>
<h2 id="question_<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>"><?php echo $result['que_id'].".".$result['que_desc'];?></h2>
<div class='align'>

<label class="containerg">
<input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>'>
<label id='ans1_<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>' for='1'><?php echo $result['ans1'];?></label>
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label class="containerg">
<input type="radio" value="2" id='radio2_<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>'>
<label id='ans2_<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>' for='1'><?php echo $result['ans2'];?></label>
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label class="containerg">
<input type="radio" value="3" id='radio3_<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>'>
<label id='ans3_<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>' for='1'><?php echo $result['ans3'];?></label>
<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>




<input type="radio" checked='checked' value="5" style='display:none' id='radio4_<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>'>
</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" class="next" id='next<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>' value='Next!' name='question'/>
</div>
<?php }?>
</form>
<div  id='result'>
Result will Appear Here test
<br/>
</div>



<script>

$(document).ready(function(){


    var steps = $('form').find(".questions");
    $(".questions").hide();
    var count = steps.length;
    steps.each(function(i){       
        if (i == 0) {   
           createNextButton(i);
           $($(".questions").get(i)).show();
        }
        else if(count==i+1){
           $($(".next").get(i)).off().on('click',function(){
              submit();
           });
        }
        else
        {
         createNextButton(i);
        }

    });
    function submit(){
// post to ajax

         $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajax.php",
                        data: $('form').serialize(),
                        success: function(msg) {
                          $("#quiz_form,#demo1").addClass("hide");
                          $('#result').show();
                          $('#result').append(msg);
                        }
         });

    }


    function createNextButton(i){

         $($(".next").get(i)).on('click',function(){
              $(".questions").hide();
              $($(".questions").get(i+1)).show();

        });
    }



});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```